# Mocking dependency in Node (mainly for unit testing)

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking

Searched for a while before raising the question.

### File structure:

```
.
|____lib
| |____bar.js
| |____baz.js
| |____foo.js
|____test
| |____bar.js
| |____baz.js
| |____foo.js
```

### Use case:

With respect to the above file structure, `./lib/foo.js` requires `./lib/bar.js`, `./lib/bar.js` requires `./lib/baz.js`.

---

While unit testing `./lib/foo.js` via `./test/foo.js`, I would like to mock `./lib/bar.js`, so that, I am only concerned with `./lib/foo.js`.
Once the tests in `./test/foo.js` are over I would like to reset/un-mock `./lib/bar.js`.

While unit testing `./lib/bar.js` via `./test/bar.js`, I would like to mock `./lib/baz.js`, so that, I am only concerned with `./lib/baz.js`. 
Once the tests in `./test/foo.js` are over I would like to reset/un-mock `./lib/baz.js`.

So on and so forth.

---

Or in other words, I would like to mock the dependencies and reset as and when required, in the test file.

Most likely mocking several times in the test file and reseting a after all the test are over in a test file.

Or may be I can control the local mock, with some file level closure variables

---

Below mentioned [StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com) posts have excellent discussion but I could not come to any conclusion.

- [Mocking a dependency in Node](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9519316/mocking-a-dependency-in-node)
- [Do I need dependency injection in NodeJS, or how to deal with …?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250851/do-i-need-dependency-injection-in-nodejs-or-how-to-deal-with)

I came across the following modules

- [mockery](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery)
- [ncore](https://github.com/Raynos/nCore)
- [horaa](https://github.com/arunoda/horaa)
- [sandboxed-module](https://github.com/felixge/node-sandboxed-module)
- [fire-up](https://github.com/analog-nico/fire-up)
- [a](https://github.com/alfateam/a)
- [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire)
- [rewire](https://github.com/jhnns/rewire/)

and [few others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9250851/do-i-need-dependency-injection-in-nodejs-or-how-to-deal-with#answer-20461486).

---

Among the above, looks like [mockery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mockery) addresses my use-case, mainly [reset/un-mock the mocked dependency](https://github.com/mfncooper/mockery#deregistering-everything).

How to achieve the same in [proxyquire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/proxyquire)?

---

Is there any other module which addresses the stated use case?

Answer (score 2):

I use a combination of [deride](https://www.npmjs.com/package/deride) and [rewire](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rewire).

For example to test `foo.js` I will:

```
var rewire = require('rewire');
var deride = require('deride');
var Foo = rewire('../lib/foo');
var mockBar, foo;

describe('something', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
      mockBar = deride.stub(['barMethod']);
      mockBar.setup.barMethod.when('bob').toReturn('Hello bob');
      Foo.__set__('bar', mockBar);
      foo = new Foo();
  });

  it('does something', function() {
    foo.someMethod('bob');
    mockBar.expect.barMethod.called.withArgs(['bob']);
  });
});
```

And there is no unsetting required.

> DISCLAIMER: I am one of the authors of deride :)